# How to convert type from ObjectId to Long when using MongoTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Normally when using spring data repositories, an object in which the result data can be stored is needed like the customer in this example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ .

In my case I'm trying to use an object which is declared in another project I'm importing using maven - let's call it `MyDoc`. The object has an attribute `Long id` while the document in the MongoDB has an addition field `_id` from type `ObjectId`. This btw is like this because the MongoDB serves as an archive and the actual `id` from MyDoc would not be unique.

In a service class I then use this the MongoTemplate to make database queries like this:

```
List<MyDoc> list = template.findAll(MyDoc.class, "DOCS");
```

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] to type [java.lang.Long]
```

How can I convert the ObjectId to a type of Long?

Alternately, I could, of course, use the java MongoDB driver but I wanted to reduce the number of dependencies to maintain since the MongoDB driver comes with the boot-starter-data-MongoDB dependency, and also hoped for a more intuitive way, in the end, to interact with the database like with the spring data repositories.

Comment: If the field in the database is an ObjectId, you should better align your model accordingly. If you want to convert it to something else, maybe String?  It certainly does not fit into a Long, it is 12 bytes long. Another option could be to completely ignore the field if you don't need it. Is your "real, but non-unique" Long id present somewhere else in the document?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is `Long Id`  from MyDoc is not unique, so it cannot act as _id of mongoDB.
Then you need to have one more _id field in your class.  By Default Spring data mongoDB will map field named id to _id in dataBase.
Essentially what you can do is create a wrapper class around `MyDoc` by extending it and then add new field of Type `ObjectId` and annotate it with `@Id`.  By that way you will have unique index and also mongoTemplate will not try to convert `_id` of database to `Long id`